# Disable Excel Popup when Mouse Over a Comment Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse, vba

Once I have placed a Comment in a cell, there exists an option to either:

- display all Comments regardless of the mouse position
- display a Comment only when the mouse hovers over a cell

Is there an option or way to temporarily disable the mouse-over effect without actually deleting all the Comments ?? Or is there a way to make the Comment and its associated text transparent ??

Comment: does this link help? http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-20803.html

Comment: @ScottCraner  Works great!! ...........if you post an *Answer*, I'll *Accept* it and the issue will be solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually turn them off by:

```
FILE ==> Options ==> Advanced ==> Display
```

And click `No comments or indicators`

Or you can set up vba with the command:

```
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = ...
```

With the `...` being one of the three choices:

```
xlCommentAndIndicator 'Display comment and indicator at all times.
xlCommentIndicatorOnly 'Display comment indicator only. Display comment when mouse pointer is moved over cell.
xlNoIndicator 'Display neither the comment nor the comment indicator at any time.
```

See these sites for more info:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835215.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839281.aspx